# Ctrl+Shift+f (Code Formatting) is not working properly in Eclipse Helios

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, code-formatting, eclipse-3.6

When I try to format code in Eclipse Helios, by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, the code is getting formatted, but the results are very ugly.  Two or three statements in one line, for example.  Indentation is also very poor.

For ex: After formatting the code it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/scannerbg">

 <include android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" layout="@layout/headerlayout" />

 <ListView android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" android:id="@+id/listView"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see in `ListView`, two to three statements are there in single line.

Can anyone offer a solution to this?

Comment: I also fatch this problem. so i use indigo.

Comment: No, but I have another m/c with Eclipse Helios only, but it works on that m/c without any problem.

Comment: I would remove `android` tag from this question. It has nothing to do with it..

Comment: I kept that tag, just to get attention from multiple users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse, from the *Window* menu select *Preferences*. Expand the *Android* node and then select the *Editors* subnode. On the right pane ensure the  "*Format XML files using the standard Android XML style..*" (the first option) is checked, and maybe other option(s).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> should work as expected and give these result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/scannerbg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/headerlayout" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I could not found "Allow single attributes to appear on the same line as their elements" under Editors tab.

Comment: I quickly edited my answer when I realized the big typo while at same time you were reading it ;-)

Comment: Oh sorry, but I could not found this "Format XML files using the standard Android XML style" also. There is nothing like this in Editors tab

Comment: Just below the "General" node in the Preferences, you should have an "Android" node for Android SDK settings. Is the Android plugin for eclipse properly installed?

Comment: There is only single checkBox asking "Autmatically format the xml edited by the visual layout editor".

Comment: Hope you will find a solution. FYI, I'm using Android Development Toolkit Version: 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395

Answer (score 1):

Use ADT version 20 for perfect formatting.

Comment: check the eclipse Helios minor version also. it should be SR2