# eclipse editor is not formatting code as specified

Tags: eclipse

Although my eclipse html editor is configured to add indentation

[image]

it is not indenting my html file correctly. I am trying to use `ctrl+shift+F` and `save action`. Could some one please help me how to enable indentation on saving or formatting.

[image]

Comment: does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176020/ctrlshiftf-code-formatting-is-not-working-properly-in-eclipse-helios

Comment: Hi Gary, the solution is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the problem. Check the current **formatter** for HTML files in your machine. For example I have default Formatter for C/C++ source files. Its is named as **K&R[built-in]**.

See below
[image]
Like this you can also check the formatter for HTML file and click on **Edit** button. New window will popup showing the all details of this formatter. Go to **Indentation** tab. In **General settings**  group, change the tab policy option from **Tab** to **Spaces** then enter the **indentation size**, save and exit then check.